# Is it permissible to Marry a Christian who has a child (out of marriage)?

Tags: nikah, love

I have met a Christian woman, who is very kind hearted and believes in the fundamentals of Islam. However, she does have a child that was born when she was a young adult and she was not married at that time. After the birth of her child she has changed her life drastically. She has started dressing more conservatively, not drinking alcohol and not eating pork/haram. This leads me to the following questions:

1. Will it be permissible for me to pursue a relationship/marriage with her if she stays Christian?
2. Will it be permissible for me to pursue a relationship/marriage with her if she converts to Islam?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, a Muslim woman can't marry a non-muslim man. But a Muslim man can marry a woman who is non-muslim but Ahle Kitab. But the purpose should be to attract her toward Islam. So, you can marry any Christian, Jewish or Sabian(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabians) woman to attract her toward Islam but can't marry any Hindu, Buddhist or any polytheist woman unless they are converted into Muslim before the marriage because they are not Ahle Kitab.

Details in Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaith_marriage_in_Islam

According to Qur'an (5:5),
"This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful for you and your food is lawful for them. And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the believers and chaste women from among those who were given the Scripture before you, when you have given them their due compensation, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret] lovers. And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers".

Answer (score -4):

Yes u can marry her even if shes practising Christian and has a child out of wedlock. May Allah bless u both